# Add a New Sublist to an Existing List

Tags: python, list, sublist

Everyone!

I am trying to add a new sublist to an existing list, but I am not quite sure on how to do it. Here is my code:

```
data = [[4,5],[3,7]]
search = 9
for sublist in data:
    if search in sublist:
        sublist.append(0)
        print("there", sublist)
        break
    else:
        print("not there")
        break
        def sublist():
            [5,6]
            print[data]
```

However, if the search is not there, the sublist does not get added to the original list. How can I do this?

Cheers!
5813

Comment: What did you expect that <s>line</s> code to do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just append it:

```
>>> data = [[4,5],[3,7]]
>>> data.append([5,6])
>>> data
[[4, 5], [3, 7], [5, 6]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You should indent your `else` block. A for/else is something completely different (although it could work in this case).

If the search *isn't* in the sublist, then append the sublist (I'm presuming you want to add `[5, 6]` to the main list) to `data`:

```
for sublist in data:
    if search in sublist:
        sublist.append(0)
        print("there", sublist)
        break
    else:
        print("not there")
        data.append([5, 6])
```

---

If you did intent to use a for/else loop, then it's as simple as doing `data.append([5, 6])` after the `else`. I don't know what you expect the function definition to do (it will do nothing just sitting there).

Comment: @WaleedKhan Clarified

Answer (score 1):

Easy.

```
data= [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
for sublist in data:
    sublist.append("a")
```